# Python: next in for loop

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I want to use `next` to skip one or more items returned from a generator. Here is a simplified example designed to skip one item per loop (in actual use, I'd test `n` and depending on the result, may repeat the `next()` and the generator is from a package I don't control):

```
def gen():
for i in range(10):
    yield i

for g in gen():
   n = next(gen())
   print(g, n)
```

I expected the result to be

```
0 1
2 3
```

etc.

Instead I got

```
0 0
1 0
```

etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're making a new generator each time you call `gen()`. Each new generator starts from 0.

Instead, you can call it once and capture the return value.

```
def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

x = gen()
for g in x:
    n = next(x)
    print(g, n)
```